# How to log unconverted files in FFMPEG due to error?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I am converting ~30,000 video files (each with different number of data/video/audio/subtitle streams) using a single batch file. I do not require data/subtitle streams. This is the code I am using for the batch file:

```
for %%i in (*.dat *.mpg *.mpeg) do ffmpeg -hide_banner -v info -n -i %%i -map 0 -dn -sn  -c:v libx264 -crf 20  -c:a aac -b:a 192k  "%%~ni.mp4" >> log.txt 2>&1
pause
```

The resulting log file that I get is 1.67gb in file size and is extremely difficult for me to go through to find the errors of files that weren't converted.

An example of a successfully converted file would look like this in the log file:

```
    Input #0, mpeg, from '571317.mpg':
  Duration: 00:05:06.02, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 2991 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:2 (mp2 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] using SAR=8/9
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] 264 - core 148 r2762 90a61ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'F:\571317.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p(top coded first (swapped)), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
    Stream #0:2: Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 aac
frame=   83 fps=0.0 q=26.0 size=     168kB time=00:00:02.70 bitrate= 508.4kbits/s speed=5.26x    
frame=  132 fps=128 q=26.0 size=     660kB time=00:00:04.41 bitrate=1224.4kbits/s speed=4.29x    
frame=  182 fps=118 q=26.0 size=    1126kB time=00:00:06.05 bitrate=1522.0kbits/s speed=3.92x    
frame=  235 fps=114 q=26.0 size=    1529kB time=00:00:07.78 bitrate=1608.5kbits/s speed=3.78x    
frame=  294 fps=114 q=26.0 size=    1867kB time=00:00:09.77 bitrate=1564.9kbits/s speed= 3.8x    
frame=  352 fps=114 q=26.0 size=    2175kB time=00:00:11.71 bitrate=1521.5kbits/s speed=3.79x    
frame=  408 fps=113 q=26.0 size=    2681kB time=00:00:13.54 bitrate=1621.1kbits/s speed=3.76x    
frame=  466 fps=113 q=26.0 size=    3276kB time=00:00:15.50 bitrate=1730.6kbits/s speed=3.77x    
[mpeg @ 000000000042a820] New subtitle stream 0:4 at pos:6483982 and DTS:17.1437s
frame=  528 fps=114 q=26.0 size=    3868kB time=00:00:17.57 bitrate=1802.4kbits/s speed=3.79x    
frame=  572 fps=111 q=26.0 size=    4508kB time=00:00:19.09 bitrate=1934.4kbits/s speed=3.71x    
frame=  611 fps=108 q=26.0 size=    5215kB time=00:00:20.43 bitrate=2090.4kbits/s speed=3.61x    
frame=  656 fps=106 q=26.0 size=    6040kB time=00:00:21.86 bitrate=2262.6kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame=  698 fps=104 q=26.0 size=    6724kB time=00:00:23.23 bitrate=2370.8kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame=  743 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    7451kB time=00:00:24.72 bitrate=2468.6kbits/s speed=3.43x    
frame=  793 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    8007kB time=00:00:26.45 bitrate=2479.7kbits/s speed=3.43x    
frame=  851 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    8495kB time=00:00:28.33 bitrate=2456.3kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame=  904 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    8992kB time=00:00:30.12 bitrate=2445.4kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame=  957 fps=103 q=26.0 size=    9475kB time=00:00:31.91 bitrate=2432.1kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame= 1014 fps=104 q=26.0 size=    9967kB time=00:00:33.81 bitrate=2414.6kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 1071 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   10297kB time=00:00:35.73 bitrate=2360.7kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 1121 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   10733kB time=00:00:37.39 bitrate=2351.1kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 1187 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   11145kB time=00:00:39.57 bitrate=2307.1kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 1241 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   11635kB time=00:00:41.36 bitrate=2304.1kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 1284 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   12291kB time=00:00:42.79 bitrate=2352.8kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 1332 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   13049kB time=00:00:44.37 bitrate=2409.0kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame= 1386 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   13608kB time=00:00:46.22 bitrate=2411.5kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 1437 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   14063kB time=00:00:47.95 bitrate=2402.3kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame= 1502 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   14504kB time=00:00:50.09 bitrate=2372.0kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 1558 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   14947kB time=00:00:51.94 bitrate=2357.2kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 1614 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   15502kB time=00:00:53.80 bitrate=2360.3kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 1668 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   16041kB time=00:00:55.63 bitrate=2361.9kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 1725 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   16509kB time=00:00:57.49 bitrate=2352.2kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 1779 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   16980kB time=00:00:59.30 bitrate=2345.4kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 1832 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   17487kB time=00:01:01.16 bitrate=2342.2kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 1886 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   17921kB time=00:01:02.93 bitrate=2332.8kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 1947 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   18284kB time=00:01:04.93 bitrate=2306.6kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 2009 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   18775kB time=00:01:06.98 bitrate=2296.1kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 2060 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   19307kB time=00:01:08.71 bitrate=2301.7kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 2113 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   19916kB time=00:01:10.48 bitrate=2314.7kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 2169 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   20374kB time=00:01:12.36 bitrate=2306.5kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 2235 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   20667kB time=00:01:14.58 bitrate=2270.0kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 2286 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   21142kB time=00:01:16.22 bitrate=2272.2kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 2340 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   21715kB time=00:01:18.05 bitrate=2278.9kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 2391 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   22368kB time=00:01:19.74 bitrate=2297.8kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 2439 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   23051kB time=00:01:21.32 bitrate=2322.0kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 2484 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   23719kB time=00:01:22.83 bitrate=2345.7kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 2528 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   24432kB time=00:01:24.33 bitrate=2373.3kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 2568 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   25074kB time=00:01:25.67 bitrate=2397.5kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 2623 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   25575kB time=00:01:27.50 bitrate=2394.2kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 2681 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   26025kB time=00:01:29.38 bitrate=2385.1kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 2734 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   26428kB time=00:01:31.17 bitrate=2374.4kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 2787 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   26856kB time=00:01:32.97 bitrate=2366.4kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 2845 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   27262kB time=00:01:34.86 bitrate=2354.0kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 2905 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   27649kB time=00:01:36.87 bitrate=2338.1kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 2958 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   28314kB time=00:01:38.66 bitrate=2350.8kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 3014 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   28794kB time=00:01:40.52 bitrate=2346.6kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 3075 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   29217kB time=00:01:42.57 bitrate=2333.5kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3129 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   29695kB time=00:01:44.36 bitrate=2330.9kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3182 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   30167kB time=00:01:46.15 bitrate=2328.0kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3240 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   30653kB time=00:01:48.09 bitrate=2323.0kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3296 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   31139kB time=00:01:49.97 bitrate=2319.6kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 3356 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   31690kB time=00:01:51.93 bitrate=2319.2kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 3417 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   32178kB time=00:01:54.00 bitrate=2312.2kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 3466 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   32767kB time=00:01:55.60 bitrate=2321.9kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 3516 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   33321kB time=00:01:57.29 bitrate=2327.3kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 3566 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   33858kB time=00:01:58.95 bitrate=2331.7kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3612 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   34515kB time=00:02:00.49 bitrate=2346.6kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 3656 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   35268kB time=00:02:02.00 bitrate=2368.0kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 3699 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   36006kB time=00:02:03.34 bitrate=2391.3kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 3742 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   36684kB time=00:02:04.84 bitrate=2407.1kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 3792 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   37287kB time=00:02:06.44 bitrate=2415.7kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 3844 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   37684kB time=00:02:08.25 bitrate=2407.0kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 3902 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   38066kB time=00:02:10.19 bitrate=2395.1kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 3960 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   38549kB time=00:02:12.07 bitrate=2391.0kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4014 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   39081kB time=00:02:13.90 bitrate=2390.8kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4071 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   39649kB time=00:02:15.80 bitrate=2391.6kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4126 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   40192kB time=00:02:17.62 bitrate=2392.4kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4180 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   40736kB time=00:02:19.47 bitrate=2392.6kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4237 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   41279kB time=00:02:21.35 bitrate=2392.3kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 4292 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   41799kB time=00:02:23.25 bitrate=2390.3kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 4346 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   42355kB time=00:02:25.00 bitrate=2392.9kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 4387 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   42997kB time=00:02:26.36 bitrate=2406.5kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4430 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   43698kB time=00:02:27.79 bitrate=2422.1kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 4478 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   44374kB time=00:02:29.35 bitrate=2433.9kbits/s speed=3.44x    
frame= 4541 fps=103 q=26.0 size=   44857kB time=00:02:31.46 bitrate=2426.1kbits/s speed=3.45x    
frame= 4607 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   45173kB time=00:02:33.68 bitrate=2407.9kbits/s speed=3.46x    
frame= 4670 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   45525kB time=00:02:35.77 bitrate=2394.1kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 4732 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   45985kB time=00:02:37.84 bitrate=2386.6kbits/s speed=3.47x    
frame= 4791 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   46416kB time=00:02:39.80 bitrate=2379.4kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 4853 fps=104 q=26.0 size=   46853kB time=00:02:41.89 bitrate=2370.8kbits/s speed=3.48x    
frame= 4914 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   47318kB time=00:02:43.88 bitrate=2365.3kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 4972 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   47760kB time=00:02:45.84 bitrate=2359.1kbits/s speed=3.49x    
frame= 5030 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   48130kB time=00:02:47.82 bitrate=2349.3kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 5092 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   48527kB time=00:02:49.87 bitrate=2340.1kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 5147 fps=105 q=23.0 size=   48906kB time=00:02:51.73 bitrate=2332.9kbits/s speed= 3.5x    
frame= 5212 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   49346kB time=00:02:53.90 bitrate=2324.5kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5270 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   49746kB time=00:02:55.82 bitrate=2317.7kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5322 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   50410kB time=00:02:57.51 bitrate=2326.3kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5369 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   51006kB time=00:02:59.11 bitrate=2332.8kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5421 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   51600kB time=00:03:00.88 bitrate=2336.9kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5478 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   52072kB time=00:03:02.76 bitrate=2334.0kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5550 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   52432kB time=00:03:05.17 bitrate=2319.6kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5614 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   52805kB time=00:03:07.34 bitrate=2309.0kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5663 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   53439kB time=00:03:08.94 bitrate=2316.9kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5710 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   53940kB time=00:03:10.54 bitrate=2319.0kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5770 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   54347kB time=00:03:12.55 bitrate=2312.1kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5830 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   54816kB time=00:03:14.49 bitrate=2308.8kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5876 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   55518kB time=00:03:16.01 bitrate=2320.3kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 5921 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   56249kB time=00:03:17.52 bitrate=2332.8kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 5976 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   56854kB time=00:03:19.33 bitrate=2336.5kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6029 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   57370kB time=00:03:21.19 bitrate=2335.9kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6081 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   57807kB time=00:03:22.90 bitrate=2333.9kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6139 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   58145kB time=00:03:24.82 bitrate=2325.6kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6189 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   58602kB time=00:03:26.48 bitrate=2324.9kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6246 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   59082kB time=00:03:28.38 bitrate=2322.6kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6304 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   59519kB time=00:03:30.34 bitrate=2318.0kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 6359 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   60028kB time=00:03:32.13 bitrate=2318.0kbits/s speed=3.51x    
frame= 6418 fps=105 q=26.0 size=   60486kB time=00:03:34.12 bitrate=2314.1kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 6478 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   60947kB time=00:03:36.10 bitrate=2310.3kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 6537 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   61412kB time=00:03:38.09 bitrate=2306.8kbits/s speed=3.52x    
frame= 6596 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   61938kB time=00:03:40.07 bitrate=2305.6kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 6658 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   62386kB time=00:03:42.14 bitrate=2300.6kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 6727 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   62836kB time=00:03:44.46 bitrate=2293.2kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 6780 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   63400kB time=00:03:46.17 bitrate=2296.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 6830 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   63962kB time=00:03:47.88 bitrate=2299.3kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 6884 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   64394kB time=00:03:49.67 bitrate=2296.8kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 6940 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   64782kB time=00:03:51.53 bitrate=2292.1kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 6994 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   65278kB time=00:03:53.36 bitrate=2291.5kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 7048 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   65778kB time=00:03:55.11 bitrate=2291.9kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 7104 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   66288kB time=00:03:56.99 bitrate=2291.4kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 7162 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   66668kB time=00:03:58.93 bitrate=2285.8kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7223 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   66988kB time=00:04:00.98 bitrate=2277.2kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7285 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   67304kB time=00:04:03.05 bitrate=2268.5kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7341 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   67682kB time=00:04:04.97 bitrate=2263.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7399 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   68156kB time=00:04:06.82 bitrate=2262.0kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7459 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   68626kB time=00:04:08.85 bitrate=2259.1kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7519 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   69070kB time=00:04:10.85 bitrate=2255.5kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7572 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   69583kB time=00:04:12.65 bitrate=2256.2kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7624 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   70046kB time=00:04:14.37 bitrate=2255.7kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7678 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   70486kB time=00:04:16.14 bitrate=2254.2kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 7726 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   70960kB time=00:04:17.74 bitrate=2255.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7768 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   71567kB time=00:04:19.15 bitrate=2262.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7816 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   72193kB time=00:04:20.75 bitrate=2268.0kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7874 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   72495kB time=00:04:22.67 bitrate=2260.9kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7933 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   72901kB time=00:04:24.64 bitrate=2256.7kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 7986 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   73449kB time=00:04:26.41 bitrate=2258.5kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8041 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   74045kB time=00:04:28.24 bitrate=2261.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8098 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   74565kB time=00:04:30.16 bitrate=2261.0kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8147 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   75117kB time=00:04:31.85 bitrate=2263.6kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8198 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   75839kB time=00:04:33.51 bitrate=2271.5kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 8248 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   76482kB time=00:04:35.22 bitrate=2276.5kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 8297 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   77092kB time=00:04:36.82 bitrate=2281.4kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 8356 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   77645kB time=00:04:38.74 bitrate=2281.9kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 8414 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   78104kB time=00:04:40.74 bitrate=2279.0kbits/s speed=3.53x    
frame= 8474 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   78606kB time=00:04:42.70 bitrate=2277.8kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8528 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   79172kB time=00:04:44.52 bitrate=2279.5kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8587 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   79795kB time=00:04:46.46 bitrate=2281.9kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8653 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   80391kB time=00:04:48.68 bitrate=2281.3kbits/s speed=3.54x    
frame= 8718 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   81021kB time=00:04:50.90 bitrate=2281.6kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 8779 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   81570kB time=00:04:52.90 bitrate=2281.3kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 8826 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   82147kB time=00:04:54.50 bitrate=2285.0kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 8882 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   82800kB time=00:04:56.36 bitrate=2288.8kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 8950 fps=106 q=26.0 size=   83343kB time=00:04:58.64 bitrate=2286.2kbits/s speed=3.55x    
frame= 9018 fps=107 q=26.0 size=   83935kB time=00:05:00.90 bitrate=2285.1kbits/s speed=3.56x    
frame= 9086 fps=107 q=26.0 size=   84481kB time=00:05:03.14 bitrate=2282.9kbits/s speed=3.56x    
frame= 9151 fps=107 q=26.0 size=   85052kB time=00:05:05.30 bitrate=2282.2kbits/s speed=3.57x    
frame= 9161 fps=106 q=-1.0 Lsize=   85813kB time=00:05:06.02 bitrate=2297.1kbits/s speed=3.56x    
video:70963kB audio:14493kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.417440%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] frame I:43    Avg QP:17.04  size: 36009
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] frame P:2866  Avg QP:20.64  size: 16000
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] frame B:6252  Avg QP:24.39  size:  4040
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  6.9% 51.7% 40.5%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] mb I  I16..4: 27.5% 65.5%  7.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] mb P  I16..4:  3.7% 12.3%  0.8%  P16..4: 35.0% 15.9%  7.6%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  0.8%  0.0%  B16..8: 42.8%  4.8%  1.0%  direct: 5.4%  skip:44.8%  L0:34.0% L1:43.7% BI:22.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] 8x8 transform intra:71.3% inter:82.4%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 65.8% 73.9% 23.9% inter: 26.4% 20.4% 1.3%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 21% 47%  5% 28%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 26% 26%  4%  4%  4%  6%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 28%  8%  4%  6%  6%  8%  4%  7%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 41% 31% 18%  9%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:3.0% UV:2.5%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] ref P L0: 61.5% 19.2% 15.3%  3.9%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] ref B L0: 83.3% 15.0%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] ref B L1: 97.3%  2.7%
[libx264 @ 000000000043c3a0] kb/s:1901.79
[aac @ 00000000004b1080] Qavg: 583.592
[aac @ 0000000000474440] Qavg: 396.171
```

And an example of a file that didn't converted (in this case due to the fact that I didn't specify to ignore subtitle stream, which I corrected by adding `-sn` to the batch file.):

```
Input #0, mpeg, from '571314.mpg':
  Duration: 00:05:44.78, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 2989 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m, top first), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:4[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

How exactly can I output a log file that simply state the files that weren't converted and the error that entails. Example:

```
000002.mpg - Not converted
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2

000123.mpg - Not converted
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

This way, I won't have to toy with a huge log file. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own so far, or are you expecting us to do your work? Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Log each process to an individual file. Delete it if process successful. Concat all remaining logs.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a solution for future runs:

I'm assuming that ffmpeg prints out errors on stderr, and returns 0 exit code upon success and value >0 upon failure.

Currently you are merging stdout with stderr, so the error messages and normal output are intermingled.

Instead you should direct stdout and stderr to different log files. The problem with that is the error messages do not include the offending file name (a pet peeve of mine). The solution is to also append the file name to the log file each time ffmpeg fails.

```
@echo off
>log.txt 2>err.txt (
  for %%F in (*.dat *.mpg *.mpeg) do (
    ffmpeg -hide_banner -v info -n -i %%F -map 0 -dn -sn -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a aac -b:a 192k "%%~nF.mp4"
    if errorlevel 1 echo %%F: FAILED&echo(
  )
)
```

The err.txt file will end up looking something like:

```
Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
571314.mpg: FAILED

Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
571315.mpg: FAILED
```

If you don't care about capturing the stdout output, then you can redirect to nul instead of log.txt. Or you could remove the stdout redirection so you can monitor the progress on your windows console.

### Here is a solution for your existing 1.67 gb log file with intermingled stdout and stderr

You can easily (and relatively quickly) parse out the failed file names and error messages with [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any windows version from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

I'm assuming that all error messages contain either the text "error" or "fail" (ignore case). You could get some false positives if a file name contains that text, but those should be easy to manually weed out.

The code below uses line continuation to make it more readable

```
@echo off
call jrepl "^ *Input #0, .*, from '(.*)':$/^.*(?:error|fail).*$"^
           "f=$2;$txt=false/$txt=f+': '+$3"^
           /t "/" /jmatchq /i /jbeg "var f" /f log.txt /o err.txt
```

The resultant err.txt should look something like:

```
571314.mpg: Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
571314.mpg: Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
571315.mpg: Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:2. Default encoder for format mp4 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
571315.mpg: Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:2
```

The logic is fairly straight forward.

- The `/F` and `/O` options define the input and output, respectively.
- The `/JBEG` option defines variable `f` during initialization
- The `/I` option ignores case
- The `/JMATCHQ` option treats the replacement string as JSCRIPT and only prints out strings assigned to `$txt`. A value of false is ignored (not printed). All unmatched text is ignored.
- The `/T` option specifies that the FIND and REPLACE (first and second) arguments are composed of a like numbered series of values delimited by `/`. In this case there are two sets of FIND/REPLACE
- The first FIND looks for the beginning of each file. The REPLACE extracts the file name and saves it to the `f` variable, and sets `$txt` to false to prevent any output.
- The second FIND looks for any line that contains error or fail. The REPLACE prefixes the line with the filename contained within `f` and assigns that to `$txt` for output.